# Expo - Error running adb: more than one device/emulator

Tags: android, adb, expo

I am running macOS Catalina, and have one Android emulator set up in the Android Virtual Device Manager.

Before starting the emulator, on a freshly rebooted system, if I run `adb devices` I get:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5562   offline
```

After starting the emulator, `adb devices` returns:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5562   offline
```

If I fire up Expo and try to run on the Android emulator, I get this error:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: more than one device/emulator
```

It looks like the offline `emulator-5562` is the problem here? But it's still there even after rebooting my computer. All the advice I've read (i.e. `adb kill-server` and `adb restart-server`) makes no difference. There are no Android devices connected via USB.

How can I delete the "offline" device? Or alternatively, how can I point Expo to the one actual Android emulator I have running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:`adb -s emulator-5554 <command>`

Comment: I don't think this is answering Alex question

Comment: It uses the "online" device. Also, it does answer, since it points Expo to the actual running emulator.